# I cant' seem to understand how you fix this error : SELECT list expression references column users which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

```
WITH base AS
(
    SELECT 
        user_value, 
        COUNT(l.user_id) AS users,
    FROM 
        table1 AS l 
    LEFT JOIN
        table 2 AS a ON l.user_id = a.user_id
    WHERE 
        DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(_PARTITIONTIME), DAY) <= 30 
        AND user_value IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
        user_value
)
SELECT
    user_value,
    users,
    users / SUM(users) AS total_users
FROM
    base
GROUP BY
    user_value
```

The base query works fine, it gives me the user_vales and how many users are in each value. Now I want to calculate the % of those users in another query. But I keep getting the same error which I have no idea how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a GROUP BY clause, every member of your SELECT clause must either be (a) part of the GROUP BY clause or (b) an aggregate function.

In this case, you need to add `users` to the GROUP BY clause of our main query.